# Как в Qt передать переменно QString значения из файла?

Tags: c++, qt

Нужно передать в переменную `QString` текст из файла, но при выполнение строка остаётся пустой:

```
QFile file("file.txt");
file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly);
QString s;
QTextStream str(&file);
s.append(str.readAll());
qDebug()<<str.readAll();
file.close();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Наиболее вероятно, что файл просто не находится. Проверяйте открыт ли файл, прежде чем работать с ним:

```
QFile file("file.txt");
if(file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly))
{
    QTextStream str(&file);
    QString s = str.readAll();
    qDebug() << s;
    file.close();
}
```

А можно ещё проще:

```
QFile file("file.txt");
if(file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly))
{
    QString s = file.readAll();
    qDebug() << s;
    file.close();
}
```

Как написал - заметил, Вы `readAll()` вызывает для `qDebug()` на объекте потока, хотя должны выводить `s`. Это тоже может дать пустой вывод(документация не упоминает, что делает `readAll()` с внутренним состоянием потока)

Comment: Глупый вопрос но как ему сказать чай файл находится в корне проекта. Написать просто "file.txt" не вариант. При написании пути например "D:\\file.txt" всё работает

Comment: Это зависит от `текущей директории`, которая выставляется той программой из которой вы запускаете Ваше приложение. К примеру, если Вы положите файл рядом с бинарником и запустите его из проводника(я так понимаю, у Вас windows), то файл будет прочитан корректно. Я не знаю, что за IDE Вы используется, но для Visual studio, по умолчанию, `текущая директория` та, где лежит файл проекта. Это можно сменить в `свойствах проекта(вкладка Debugging)->Working Directory`

Answer (score 0):

Если вы работаете в QtCreator, и запускаете через него, то посмотреть рабочий каталог можно во вкладке "Проекты"(меню иконок слева). Далее во вкладке запуск пункт "Рабочий каталог"